# What is wrong with this code (SCILAB)?

Tags: math-software

i wrote this on scilab:

> function q=arrow(x0,y0,z0,a0,r,s)
>       j=1;
>
> ```
> while norm(gradJ(x0,y0,z0) - gradF(x0,y0,z0))>10^-10
>     a0 = max(0, a0 + s*f(x0,y0,z0));
>     [x0;y0;z0] = [x0;y0;z0] - r*(gradJ(x0,y0,z0)+a0*gradF(x0,y0,z0));
>     j=j+1;
> end
>
> gradJ=[x0;y0;z0];
> q=[gradJ;j];
> endfunction
> ```

i got this error message: "Instruction left hand side: waiting for a dot or a left parenthesis."

i dont understand. Someone see any error?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the "j=1" statement on a new line (actually I think you have - it's just the formatting here that makes it look like it's on the same line as the "function" command) and putting a semicolon after "endfunction":

> ```
> function q=arrow(x0,y0,z0,a0,r,s)
>  j=1;
>
>  while norm(gradJ(x0,y0,z0) - gradF(x0,y0,z0))>10^-10
>      a0 = max(0, a0 + s*f(x0,y0,z0));
>      [x0;y0;z0] = [x0;y0;z0] - r*(gradJ(x0,y0,z0)+a0*gradF(x0,y0,z0));
>      j=j+1;
>  end
>
>  gradJ=[x0;y0;z0];
>  q=[gradJ;j];
>  endfunction;
> ```